# Which fraction $\dfrac{p}{q}$, where $p,q$ are positive integers less than $100$, is closest to $\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: number-theory

> Which fraction $\dfrac{p}{q}$, where $p,q$ are positive integers less than $100$, is closest to $\sqrt{2}$? Find all digits after the decimal point in the decimal representation of this fraction that coincided with digits in the decimal representation of $\sqrt{2}$ (without using any tables).

Firstly, what do they mean by "without using any tables"? Do they mean without just remembering what $\sqrt{2}$ is? Also, in the solution below how do they get the bound $7 \cdot 10^{-5} < \dfrac{p}{q}-\sqrt{2} < 8 \cdot 10^{-5}$?

**Book's solution:**

[image]

Comment: This is related to the [continued fraction expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) of $\sqrt2$. The note "without using any tables" seems to mean "by proving said inequality", because this inequality also shows that the first four digits must match (else the difference would be at least $10^{-4}$)

Comment: @AlexR I thought by "without using tables" it means "don't use long division to compute $\dfrac{99}{70} = 1.4128\ldots$ and your memorization to compute $\sqrt{2} = 1.41421\ldots$".

Answer (score 3):

There is a more clear way to solve this by using the simple continued fraction for $x=\sqrt{2}$:

$$x^2=2$$

$$x^2-1=1$$

$$(x-1)(x+1)=1$$

$$x-1=\frac{1}{1+x}$$

$$x=1+\frac{1}{1+x}=1+\cfrac{1}{1+1+\cfrac{1}{1+x}}=1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{1+x}}}=\dots$$

Finally, we obtain the simple continued fraction for $\sqrt{2}$:

$$\sqrt{2}=1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2+\cdots}}}}$$

Now, all the best rational approximations of $\sqrt{2}$ (with the smallest possible denominator) can be obtained from this continued fraction by truncating it.

This way we get the following sequence of approximants:

$$\frac{p_k}{q_k}=\{1, \frac{3}{2} , \frac{7}{5}, \frac{17}{12}, \frac{41}{29},  \frac{\bf 99}{\bf 70} , \frac{239}{169},\dots \}$$

As you can see, the answer is really $\frac{99}{70}$, because the better approximation has $p,q>100$.

---

This way is a little long, and you need to take for granted the fact that a simple continued fraction really gives the best rational approximants.

But I agree that the 'solution' in your textbook is not very clear.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2 for reference.

Comment: How does the book get the bound?

Comment: @user19405892, it seems to me they just use the known digits of $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: I mean the fact that $7 \cdot 10^{-5} < \dfrac{p}{q}-\sqrt{2} < 8 \cdot 10^{-5}$.

Comment: @user19405892 You have $$\biggl\lvert \frac{p}{q} - \sqrt{2}\biggr\rvert = \frac{\lvert p^2-2q^2\rvert}{q(p+q\sqrt{2})}$$ when $p,q > 0$. With $p = 99,\, q = 70$, you get $$\frac{99}{70} - \sqrt{2} = \frac{1}{70(99 + 70\sqrt{2})}.$$ Using $98 < 70\sqrt{2} < 99$ gives you better bounds, so you can get the given bounds with fairly coarse estimates.

Comment: @DanielFischer So we get $\dfrac{1}{7 \cdot 13790}> \dfrac{p}{q}-\sqrt{2} > \dfrac{1}{7 \cdot 13860}$. How does that translate to $7 \cdot 10^{-5} < \dfrac{p}{q}-\sqrt{2} < 8 \cdot 10^{-5}$?

Comment: Not quite, @user19405892, you get $\frac{1}{13790} > \frac{99}{70} - \sqrt{2} > \frac{1}{13860}$. Now clearly $\frac{1}{13790} < \frac{1}{12500} = 8\cdot 10^{-5}$ and $\frac{1}{13860} > \frac{1}{14000} \approx 7.07142857\cdot 10^{-5} > 7\cdot 10^{-5}$. Doing long division (or asking your calculator) you get better bounds.

Comment: @DanielFischer Also, how do we know $\dfrac{99}{70}$ best approximates $\sqrt{2}$ using $(1)$?

Comment: @user19405892 Because $99^2 - 2\cdot 70^2 = 1$, and $99$ is the largest integer less than $100$.